# How to download latest java version 8 using powershell script

Tags: java, powershell, packer

I'm using below commands to install Java on one of the Windows packer instance however, I am getting below error as;

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:94
+ ... content | %{[regex]::matches($_, '(?:<a title="Download Java software ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Commands:-

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"

$URL = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).Content | %{[regex]::matches($_, '(?:<a title="Download Java software for Windows .64-bit." href=")(.*)(?:">)').Groups[1].Value}

Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -OutFile jre8.exe $URL

Start-Process .\jre8.exe '/s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0' -wait
```

Looks like Oracle has removed the title string contents from webpage which is causing the error.
Is there an another way/command to install it using powershell?

Comment: Check the result you get from the web request. It says JavaScript need to be enabled, so this won't work.

Comment: @marsze, I am not getting that error which you are getting. Well, I have removed regex and used direct download link using `Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=242990_a4634525489241b9a9e1aa73d9e118e6 -OutFile jre8.exe`
which then downloads the jre8.exe.
Further I have executed `Start-Process .\jre8.exe '/s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0' -wait` but nothing happens.

Comment: @LukasKörfer, yes I did refer that url and tried installing java using chocolatey. Setup was getting downloaded but it is failing at the installation with below error;

`Installing JRE 8.0.2610.12 32-bit
Installing JRE8...
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\jre8\8.0.2610.12\JRE8x86.exe" /s  REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 ] was not successful. Exit code was '1'. See log for possible error messages.
The install of jre8 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jre8\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.`

Comment: Initially, I was running `Invoke-WebRequest` from aws system manager console but then I ran it from rdp server using powershell and it worked. Java got successfully downloaded and installed.
But this worked without using regex string which I was using earlier in problem statement. For regex, I need to do some more engineering.